# Вывод конкретной записи WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, как осуществить вывод конкретной записи на странице при помощи функции в WordPress?

Comment: Можете уточнить? Вы хотите вывести конкретную строку? Тогда можно отредактировать шаблон.

Comment: Мне надо вывести запись с заголовком Преимущество и с его полным содержимым

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите код который сейчас есть, дайте пример желаемого и фактического результата. Очень сложно без этого понять, что такое «заголовок Преимущество».

Comment: У меня есть запись с именем Преимущество, в которой есть текст, как мне вывести эту запись?

Comment: Я написал вам инструкцию, если вы все правильно имели ввиду, то должны вывести пост в своей теме.

Answer (score 3):

domain.com/?p=номер поста.
Дальше заходишь в меню и выводишь там, где тебе нужно при помощи произвольных ссылок. Номер поста можно получить внутри редактора.
Я так понял вам нужно это для видоизменения страницы, для это используются произвольные поля.